# Failed to bind to address (already in use) error with Visual Studio Mac API

Tags: macos, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm attempting to create a Web API via .Net Core. I'm just using the boilerplate ValuesController as a Hello World. When I run the project, I get the following error:

```
System.IO.IOException: "Failed to bind to address https://127.0.0.1:5001: address already in use." ---> System.Exception {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException}: "Address already in use" ---> System.Exception {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}: "Address already in use"
  at at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.BindAsync()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.BindAsync()\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass22_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)\n   at Sysmex.Unity.Interfaces.WebAPI.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/mharrison/Developer/unity-interfaces/Sysmex.Unity.Interfaces.WebAPI/Sysmex.Unity.Interfaces.WebAPI/Program.cs:17
```

I'm assuming this is just a simple setting problem, but I haven't been able to find anything while Googling. Is there anything that I need to set to allow me to debug the project on Mac OS?

Comment: While this may not be a solution to the underlying problem, a quick fix to get it working again is to execute `kill -9 $(lsof -i:PORT -t) 2> /dev/null`, where PORT is the port that is claimed to be already in use (e.g., 5001)

Answer (score 82):

Sure you can change the port every time you get that error or even restart your computer, here is the correct way to go about this

Find what is running on that port and kill the process

Terminal on macOS:

Find the process number:

```
lsof -i: <port number>
```

e.g.

```
lsof -i:5001
```

Then kill the process number:

```
kill -9 <process number / PID>
```

e.g.

```
kill -9 1600
```

Comment: I know the answer is specific to MAC but also works fine on Linux as well. (I know MAC is Linux only but just put it here if someone doesn't know that :) )

Comment: On UBUNTU: `sudo kill -9 'sudo lsof -t -i:5001'`

Comment: You need to specify the protocol (TCP or UDP): `lsof -i tcp:<PORT>`

Answer (score 26):

I know this is late answer. But it may be helpful to somebody.

There seems a bug with MAC Visual Studio, it always goes https://127.0.0.1/5001.

If you right click on your project, select options. Then Project Options Dialog will appear. On the left pane, goto Run->Configurations->Default, then on the right pane select ASP.Net Core tab. There is App URL which is being used by default. Change it to your needs.

[image: Change IP address in App URL]

Comment: I changed it but still it doesn't work when I change it and then run it it again gives an error and when I check the url is again https://localhost:5001http://localhost:5000

Comment: @Amit, you saved my day. Works for me! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I've changed mine to be different ports in the launchSettings.json and in webBuilder.UseUrls and it STILL uses different ports than what I put in there.

Answer (score 18):

**Assuming that you are using default port:**

this usually happens when a process gets corrupt and is disconnected from visual studio.

If you are on mac, open activity monitor and kill the process by name "dotnet"

**If you are using a non standard port:** then you need to change the port number to an available one. There is a solution from Amit on this thread, use that to change the port.

Comment: most simple answer and solution. I had two stale dotnet processes when this happened to me. should have far more upvotes.

Answer (score 13):

On Mac, just finding the process and killing it didn't work. We need to kill the process number.

```
lsof -i: <port number>
```

e.g.

```
lsof -i:5001
```

and kill the process number

```
kill -9 <process number / PID>
```

e.g.

```
kill -9 438
```

Reason why is that the process  using the port was named ControlCenter, which is a native macOS application and it will restart immediately after killing the process.

What finally worked for me was this:

The process running on this port turns out to be an AirPlay server. You can deactivate it in `System Preferences › Sharing, and unchecking AirPlay Receiver` to release port 5000

Comment: this is not working and even if it work. it is definitely not the permanent solution. it will come again and again and it is boring and time wasting to kill a process every time.

Comment: it works for me and many others :) i'm sorry that it doesn't help you. For me it's a good solution as i only do it once or twice a year and it takes me 2 seconds to do it :) And the part for the AirPlay was only needed the one time ofc...

Answer (score 11):

The port 5001 has already used in your system. Change port number to 5002 or whatever you want.

You can add port number with **.UseUrls** into **CreateWebHostBuilder**

```
  public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5002")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Or if you use visual studio code, just replace **args** section in **.vscode -> launch.json**.

```
"args": ["urls=http://localhost:5002"]
```

Comment: now it is in the launchsettings.json   "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5002",

Answer (score 9):

The port 5001 has already used in your system.

Windows, use task manager to kill the processes "dotnet core host"

Mac, force quit 'dotnet' in Activity Monitor app

[image]

Comment: you would force quit 'dotnet' in Activity Monitor app for Mac

Answer (score 9):

For those who come here because they updated to MacOs Monterey. It has services listening by default on ports 5000 and 7000.

If you are blocked on those ports, running `lsof -i tcp:5000` (or 7000) will show something like:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ControlCe 371 me   17u  IPv4 0xad81aeb96e1d0669      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
ControlCe 371 me   18u  IPv6 0xad81aeb9709a5f91      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

For now, you can manually stop the OS from listening on these ports by **unchecking AirPlay Receiver** in the Apple menu -> System Preferences -> Sharing section.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332

Comment: Thanks, this answer finally helped me!

Answer (score 6):

If you are on Mac, you can find the process running on a port with `lsof -i tcp:<PORT>`.

To kill the process running on a port, you may try `npx kill-port <PORT>`

Answer (score 3):

Although an old post, when I got this the other day I thought id post my resolution

I could see port it was in the system reserve list using

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143246/unable-to-start-kestrel-system-io-ioexception-failed-to-bind-to-address-http]

```
 netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

so I tried to reserver this port using

```
netsh int ipv4 remove excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=5000 numberofports=1
```

But I got

> The error message I get back is: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

I tried all the following

```
net stop winnat
net stop WwanSvc
net stop LanmanWorkstation
net stop http
net stop W3SVC
iisreset /stop
```

and I tried killing the application Frame Host and Adobe processes, I even rebooted my pc but still, the error remained.

I eventually worked out it was the process "intel graphics command centre", when I re-installed the dotnet SKD and it failed to install because this process was blocking it. I did not want to have to use another port as .NET has always been on port 5000 and I should not need to alter by builds just to accommodate some other process, I hope this helps someone someday

see https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/Intel-Graphic-Command-Center-using-port-5000/m-p/1519268 for more info

Answer (score 2):

Got a similar Error on my project on port 5002 on Visual studio for MAC 2019,
restarting Visual studio did nothing.

**i shutdown the machine and relaunched**

it's a safer solution i think.

Comment: so you suggest us to restart the machine every time we have this problem :D

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a bug in Visual Studio for Mac. Here is a solution to fix it manually:

1- Open **"Run"** menu from the top -> **"Run with"** -> **"Custom Configuration"**. Then go to **"ASP.NET Core"** tab and copy the **"App Url"** value. (It's your App's correct port)

2- Now you should paste it inside your project option default run config:
in Solution panel, right click on your project and click on **"options"** -> **"Run"** -> **"Configuration"** -> **"Default"**. Then go to **"ASP.NET Core"** tab and paste the copied value in App Url box.

Now run your project.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to at least temporarily solve this issue by implementing a workaround provided by Bill Boga on his site here: https://www.billbogaiv.com/posts/setting-aspnet-host-address-in-net-core-2

The key for my project was to add .UseUrls(urls: "http://localhost:10000") in the BuildWebHost function. Like so:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using OrchardCore.Logging;
using OrchardCore.Modules;

namespace ShiftBrandSite
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseNLogWeb()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls(urls: "http://localhost:10000") // <-- localhost urls
                .Build();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To complement Amit's answer: Option to change port setting while debugging an ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio 2019 is as below:

Go to Project Properties > Debug tab > Web Server Settings section > App URL field

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Linux Ubuntu Solution:

Just kill the process/port

```
sudo kill -9 'sudo lsof -t -i:5001'
```

Might work on MAC as well not sure.

Answer (score 0):

For windows users who are experiencing this error on a .netcore webapi a quick fix would be to change the port number in your application url which can be found in the found in the launchSettings.json file under the properties folder in Visual Studio IDE.

```
    "profiles": {
  "https": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": true,
    "launchBrowser": false,
    "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
    **"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5002;http://localhost:5003",** 
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
```

There are certainly other ways to resolve this, but this was a quick approach I used. For example, after changing the port no. in the application url I used https://localhost:5002/weatherforecast for the weatherforecast api.

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to restart my mac, then it was all good again.

I did not try to kill dotnet from activity monitor but if it will happen again i will give it a try.