# Unable to start Kestrel. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, centos7, asp.net-core-2.1

I followed the steps from this URL to publish .NET core 2.1 web application code to Linux Centos 7 server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I tried to run "sudo dotnet application_name.dll". I received this following error message. Am I missing something? I published code using Visual Studio 2017 on windows machine and copied code to Linux server.

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use. ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Address already in use ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Address already in use
```

### Program.cs

```
  public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

### Startup.cs config

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
    }
```

launchSettings.json:

```
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
```

Answer (score 88):

Restarting this service may [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67442253/2116114) the issue : **Host Network Service** on windows Services program

Comment: Restarting "Host Network Service" also solved this issue for me.

Comment: Worked for me as well. This should be marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 39):

Goto Powershell in admin mode and write the following command:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

Check port exclusion ranges whether your port falls under this list; if yes then use the following commands:

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

The issue should be resolved.

Comment: This is helpful for me

Comment: How to find if a port is in reserved or not? Export reserved ports into excel, then use below fomula to find if requested port is in range or not. `=IF(AND($C$1<=B2؛A2<=$C$1)؛"ERROR"؛"")`

Comment: =IF(AND($C$1<=B2;A2<=$C$1);"ERROR";"")

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I was able to work around this by changing the port Kestrel was using.  Here are two options that worked for me (pick one):

1. Add an "applicationUrl" setting to the launchSettings.json file (found under the Properties folder in VS2019).  Using "https://localhost:5201" in the example below:

   ```
   "profiles": {
     "IIS Express": {
         ...
         "environmentVariables": {
           "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
         },
       "Host": {
         ...
       }
     },
     "Your.App.Namespace.Api": {
       ...
       "environmentVariables": {
         "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
       },
       "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5201;http://localhost:5200"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Add a "UseUrls" fluent method invocation to the WebHostBuilder in Program.Main().  i.e. "http://localhost:5200/" in the example below:

   ```
   using (var host = new WebHostBuilder()
   .UseKestrel(o => o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
   ...
   .UseStartup<Startup>()
   .UseUrls("http://localhost:5200/")
   ```

Comment: I found option #1 (launchsettings) only applies when running from the dev environment.  Option #2 works even in deployment

Answer (score 12):

It is happening because there is already a task running at the port.

1. Open cmd with administration mode
2. Run netstat -aon
3. Find the PID for the port not working
4. Kill the process for the PID. Ex - taskkill /F /PID 5200

Comment: Tried a few ways, this one Saloni provided resolved my issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This works for me with Windows 10

Open CMD Prompt as Administrator and run:

```
net stop hns
net start hns
```

Killing processes by port, restarted my Visual Studio, but did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

After Windows 10 Update KB4074588, some ports are reserved by Windows and applications cannot bind to these ports. 50067 is in the blocked range.

You can use netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp to list the reserved ranges.

excludedportrange list

[image]

ref Issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1486417/unable-to-start-kestrel-getting-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way

Comment: This solve the problem for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just restart IIS then remove and create a website again and it's works fine!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac "Kestrel doesn't support HTTP/2 with TLS on macOS and older Windows versions such as Windows 7" please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-6.0#unable-to-start-aspnet-core-grpc-app-on-macos for more details. A quick fix (only DEV ) is to remove the HTTPS URL from `applicationUrl` in the launchsettings.json

```
...
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5126",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is easily resolved by changing the Port number.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using VS for macOS, however, I was getting sick of VS for macOS's lack of quality, so switched to JetBrains Rider, quit VS, and this particular problem disappeared.

Also, using VS for macOS, the ports specified in launchsettings.json were being ignored, but using Rider, they are being used.

Comment: I resolved the error running ```dotnet clean``` command and killing all ```dotnet``` processes in ```Activity Monitor``` app

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me.

List of running ports:

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P | grep :5000
```

Kill manually running port like 5000:

```
sudo kill -9 sudo lsof -t -i:5000
```