# Failed to bind to LocalHost (invalid exception) error Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, localhost

I'm building a brand new ASP.Net Core MVC project. When I try to run it in the debugger, I get this error:

```
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=Failed to bind to address https://localhost:5001.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.<BindAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An invalid argument was supplied.) (An invalid argument was supplied.)

Inner Exception 2:
SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied.
```

The error occurs in my Program.cs class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); //<-- ERROR BREAKS HERE
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52649979/failed-to-bind-to-address-already-in-use-error-with-visual-studio-mac-api) getting a similar issue, however my problem is not that the address is already in use, and I am not on a mac. I have updated to the most recent VS version, 17.1.0 at time of writing, but the error persists.

Can anyone offer advice?

EDIT: I tried using the localhost port numbers that were assigned to the application at create time, 7161 and 5161, and I get the same error: "SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied."

I've also tried opening the port in Windows Firewall. No change.

EDIT 2: Here's the code in Startup.cs as well.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        // declare external services and database contexts

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddHsts(options =>
        {
            options.Preload = true;
            options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
            options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        });

        // Adds the HTTPS Redirect
        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
            options.HttpsPort = 5001;
        });

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.Cookie.Name = "GLEntry.Authentication";
        });

        // Add IHttpContextAccessor
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddMvc();

        // May need this for application authentication? 
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the message is clear, it can't bind the address, and that's caused because it's in use... Check again for open ports (or maybe you're trying to execute two projects in the same port?)

Comment: you have to post the startup too since you use it in your webbuilder

Comment: @Serge startup posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this makes absolutely no sense, but I was able to get it working by setting the debugger to use "IIS Express", instead of the project name. It's the dropdown next to the green "play" button in VS; not sure what that setting's called.

Anyway, that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 27):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70915818/13242440

In the command line, on behalf of the administrator:

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core, It is resolved by changing the port number specified in the launchSettings.json file for me.

##### To fix the issue, follow these steps:

- Locate the launchSettings.json file in your ASP.NET Core project. It is typically located in the Properties or Properties/launchSettings folder.
- Open the launchSettings.json file and locate the profile you are using for running the application. The profile names are usually IIS Express or Kestrel.
- Within the profile settings, locate the applicationUrl property. This property specifies the URL and port number that the development server should listen on.
- Change the port number to a different value that is not being used by any other application. For example, you can change it from "https://localhost:5001" to "https://localhost:5002".
- Save the launchSettings.json file.

Answer (score 0):

That has happened to me recently.
What I did to be able to still use Swagger (which is what starts when you press the run button as your projects name (and not IIS for example)) is the following :

1. Change my App URL under my project's properties. Somehow, I had two localhost with different ports (one being 7255 and the other being 5255).
2. I verified that my launchSettings.json (@ Properties/lanchSettings.json) were correct and up to date (some swagger launchSettings can sometimes go outdated)

Trough those steps, I found out that 5255 (my second App URL) was causing this whole issue.